# Corona sdk pass value from main.lua to external module

Tags: module, lua, coronasdk

Here is a demo I modified to remove the module(..., package.seeall) statement. It works great, and I want to use the same idea in a Corona sdk project. I want to pass a value to an existing variable that I created in the demo. Thanks for any advice.

main.lua--------------------------------------------------

```
-- Load external library (should be in the same folder as main.lua)
local testlib = require("testlib")
testlib.testvar = 100 -- Trying to change the testvar value in external module

-- cache same function, if you call more than once
local hello = testlib.hello

-- now all future invocations are "fast"
hello()


-- This all works fine, but I need to change the value of testvar.
```

testlib.lua -----------------------------------------------------

```
local M = {}
local testvar = 0 -- I need to change the value of this variable as well as others later.
print("testvar=",testvar)

local function hello()
    print ("Hello, module")
end
M.hello = hello

return M
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case Your `local testvar` is private variable for Your module (`testlib.lua`).

You need to provide some setters/getters for that private variable.

Basic example would be adding this to Your `testlib.lua`:

```
function setter(new_val)
    test_var = new_val
end

function getter()
    return test_var
end

M.set = setter
M.get = getter
```

Now, You can use `testlib.set("some new value..")` and `print(testlib.get())` in Your `main.lua` to operate the value of `testvar` variable.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I tried that. For some reason, anything assigned in setter returns nil in the getter function.

Comment: @jadkins4, It doesn't work as exchange between different instances of `main.lua` or different instances of Lua VM. If I get You right...

Comment: Only one instance of main.lua. I am trying to pass a value to an external module testlib.lua. I have declared the test_var variable at the top of testlib.lua and need to change it to different values when I execute functions inside testlib.lua. I don't really need the value returned to main.lua, but when I print the value of setter inside testlib.lua outside the setter function, it returns nil. I tried making it global, but it is still nil.